# extracting data between having { } any other method with good run time

Tags: c++, string

I have this piece of code where am extracting the data between the { }, and this takes me around O(n) is there any other method which is more effcient

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   const char *blah = "[{post:banb {bbbbbbbb}: ananmsdb},{dsgdf{9090909090}fdgsdfg}";
   std::string op;
   unsigned int i = 0;    
   int im = 0;
   int found = 0;
   while(strlen(blah) != i){
       if(blah[i] == '{'){
         found = 1;  
         // copy what ever u got
         op+=blah[i];
         im++;  
       }
       else if(blah[i] == '}'){
           //copy wat ever u got
           op+=blah[i];
           im--;
       }
       if(found ==1){
           //copy wat ever u got.
           op+=blah[i];
       }

       if(found ==1 && im == 0)   {
           found = 0;
           cout << op <<endl;
           op.clear()  ;
           // u have found the full one post so send it for processing.
       }
i++;
}
}
```

output :post:banb {bbbbbbbb}: ananmsdb
        dsgdf{9090909090}fdgsdfg

Comment: Honestly, this looks way more C than C++.

Comment: How could you improve on O(N)?  you have to examine every character until you find the closing brace, otherwise you might miss a closing brace in the characters you didn't examine.

Comment: You should read up on how `strlen` works.

Comment: Have you profiled the code to see where it is spending its time?

Answer (score 3):

No. You can use library functions to make this code shorter, but it will never be more efficient than `O(n)` where `n` is the length of the input string, since you need to examine each character at least once because each one could potentially be a token that you need to extract.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can improve on O(n) for the underlying *algorithm*, but you can probably improve your *implementation*.

Currently your implementation may well be O(n^2) rather than O(n), as `strlen()` could be called on every iteration (unless your compiler is particularly smart). You should probably cache the call to `strlen()` explicitly, e.g. change:

```
while(strlen(blah) != i){
    ...
```

to:

```
const int len = strlen(blah);
while(len != i){
    ...
```

Comment: Please explain how this makes the algo better then O(n). I assume you are asserting that this code does that, given that's what the question asks.

Comment: It doesn't improve on the O(n), but if the compiler fails to spot that the string isn't being changed, it may mean that the strlen is called for every iteration in the loop. And that will be slower than not calling `strlen` every iteration. If the string is sufficiently long, this may well dominate the entire loop.

Answer (score 0):

As everybody else has said there is no way to make this faster as you have to check every character incase you miss one.

But, this being said if perhaps you already knew some information about the data aka how many pairs of '{' and'}' then I can onlythink of one way(besides sorting but that brings it back to O(n) + etc).

This would be to choose indexes between 0 - x and randomly check at spots if you can find the '{' or '}'. Just to be clear this will only work if you know how many '{' and '}'s are already in the set of data.

Edit: Addtionally the copy you provided (just from using notepad) when it hits the first cout<< it should output "{{post:banb {{bbbbbbbb}}: ananmsdb}}", as its creating additional {'s and }'s.